# Entity Framework will not recognize webpage_UsersInRoles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

I am using EF5 VS2012 and using SimpleMembership.  I have let MS auto-create the SQL tables

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("SqlRoleManagerConnection", "webpages_Users", "UserID", "Username", true);
```

And whenever I attempt to create a model from DB to create EDMX, it omits the webpages_UsersInRoles table.  There are references to this table in the XML but it does not appear on the diagram and no classes are generated for it.  I am running VS2012 Update 1 so this is not related to the commonly reported bug.  I have also manually selected Run Custom Tool which does not fix.

As you probably know, this missing table only contains two FK fields to link the Users and Roles tables.

I have attempted creating a new project and new EDMX files and they all produce the same result - missing webpages_UsersInRoles diagram & classes.

EDIT: I can repeating go into Update from DB and select the table and it will not add to the diagram or class.  What is the reason for this behavior and how can I force EF to connect everything so I can use this table and class?

[image]

Comment: What's the question? Do you need this table in the diagram after all? Will will handle anything directly in this table? I guess that if it's not there when you create the `EDMX`, then it's because it's not necessary.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi Without this table you cannot make the relationships and without the class I can't reference it in code. I tried adding a class manually that would mimic what the EDMX would generate, it compiles, but I still cannot access it in code.  This behavior is quite strange which you should be able to repro given the example above.

Comment: I have the same problem as you do, do you have the fix yet?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen nothing yet, please post if you discover anything.

Comment: @Vic Ok, so I open file *.edmx.diagram and I see that webpages_UsersInRole is a AssociationConnector not an EntityTypeShape.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you don't reference that table directly in your code. You work with the `Membership` API.

Here's a good post to read about it: [Seeding Membership & Roles in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/09/05/seeding-membership-amp-roles-in-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx)

Sample code:

```
private void SeedMembership()
{
    if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
    {
        Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
    }

    if (!Roles.RoleExists("Teacher"))
    {
        Roles.CreateRole("Teacher");
    }

    if (!Roles.RoleExists("Student"))
    {
        Roles.CreateRole("Student");
    }

    if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("leniel"))
    {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("leniel", "mypass");
    }

    if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("leniel").Contains("Administrator"))
    {
        Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "leniel" }, new[] { "Administrator" });
    }

    if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("tester"))
    {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("tester", "test123");
    }

    if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("tester").Contains("Administrator"))
    {
        Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "tester" }, new[] { "Administrator" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Good article for seeding db. Maybe I am just going about it wrong, but i am not using a membership provider.  I am running an Intranet webapp using domain auth and trying to write code to be able to manage the domain accounts and roles that are permitted to access parts of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the way EF works with Many-To-Many relationships,
below are 2 explanations and how to work with them:

http://nileshhirapra.blogspot.in/2012/03/entity-framework-insert-operation-with.html

http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/08/21/many-to-many-mappings-in-entity-framework.aspx